# UIMA with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, uima

as said in [here](https://spark-summit.org/2014/leveraging-uima-in-spark/)
there are some overlap between UIMA and spark in distribution infrastructures. I was planning to use UIMA with spark. (now i am moving to UIMAFit) Can any one tell me what are the problems we really face when we develop uima with spark.
And what are the possible encounters. 
(Sorry I haven't done any research on this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is accessing objects because UIMA tries to re instantiate objects when running their analyse engines. if the objects has local references  then there will be a problem with accessing from a remote spark cluster. some RDD functions might not work within UIMA context.  however if you don't use a separate remote cluster then there won't be a problem. (I am talking about uima-fit 2.2)

Comment: Thank you very Much @Hasitha